# Lambda loop thru ICollection failed to find object property

Tags: c#, lambda, icollection

I have a list of objects as `ICollection<objectA> listA`. Now I'm trying to loop thru this listA and trying to match a condition and assign the result found into a variable. I tried below:

```
varB.someDesc = listA.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.ID == varB.ID).someDesc
```

Error complaining that `x.ID` is object null reference. When I put a break point, I can see there are many items in listA and there is an attribute `ID`. May I know what goes wrong?

Comment: What is the exact error message? I suspect it may be complaining about the result of `FirstOrDefault` being null, and not `x.ID` as you say in your question. That would indicate that there is no item in the list with a matching ID.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest validating the return value of FirstOrDefault() as follows:

```
var item = listA.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.ID == varB.ID);
if (item != null)
    varB.someDesc = item.someDesc;
```

The error might not be exactly what you think it is.

Comment: Just to elaborate, `FirstOrDefault()` returns the first matching record, or the default of the selected type if no match was found. For classes the default is `null`, for primitive types you can look it up (e.g. `int` is 0, `bool` is false, etc).

Answer (score -2):

Try this code.

```
varB.someDesc = listA.Where(x=>x.ID == varB.ID).FirstOrDefault().someDesc
```

you better check Object Null before assigning.

Comment: Your code and the code listed by the OP is functionally equivalent.